# How to iterate on a list?

Tags: plugins

I am an end-user for Word-Press and i am sorry in advance if my question is very simple.

I have a list that I would like to distribute to whoever opt-in in my form. 
The list is unique combination discount coupons that I get from the manufacturer. 
An Example for this list:
1- UKM1
2- SHJM
3- SOHU

So I am using Contact7 to get the opt-ins, and the replay supposed to be:
" Thank you! Here is your Coupon XXXXX"

While using Contact7 I am only able to send a reply of a static information, but what I am trying to achieve is replacing the XXXXXX with the dynamic coupon number from the Coupon list.

My questions are as below: 
1- Is there any plugin where I can provide the list that I want to distribute?
2- Is there a way to make the response dynamic without coding?
3- Is there a way to get notified if the list got low where I need to replenish a new list?

Comment: Hello Joe - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes are considered off-topic here as they require very intimate knowledge of very niche code in order to answer well. Questions asking for plugin recommendations are likewise considered off-topic. Please take a moment to review the "[ask]" page in our [help]. All of that said, I'd recommend hitting up Contact7 community/support channels. This sounds like a situation that has likely come up before - they may well have an excellent solution already worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without coding will be difficult. Contact Form 7 is meant to send out emails after form submission, not much more. You need a callback function that you can use to implement your coupon logic.

One possible solution:

Install the [Redirect Addon for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/) and configure it to redirect to a local page, ie. "thankyou". On this page, you could place a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), which will provide you with the necessary callback function to retrieve a coupon code from the list and return it to the user.

Other than that, you could hook into [wpcf7_before_send_mail](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.5/actions/wpcf7_before_send_mail/), which has the benefit of being able to access the POST data (which will be gone after a redirect).

Yet another way would be to have your own shortcode within the mail body, ie. [coupon_code]. Here's how you could use this to display the coupon code in the outgoing mail: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-shortcode-in-emails/